# Postfix: virtual_alias_maps delivering everything to one user despite new domain

Tags: email, postfix, domain, alias

I have a [`postfix`](http://www.postfix.org/) installation handling mail for a couple of domains, for which all mail goes to one real local user (`cmb`), and I want to add a new domain (let's call it `example.org`) for a second user, but everything is being delivered to `cmb`. Here is `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
chris@boyle.name cmb
@chris.boyle.name cmb
@cmb.is-a-geek.org cmb
@example.org newperson
```

Here is most of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, full file on request. I have not set `luser_relay`.

```
myhostname = nova.chris.boyle.name
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = chris.boyle.name
mydestination = chris.boyle.name, nova.chris.boyle.name, nova, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mynetworks_style = host
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
virtual_alias_domains   = cmb.is-a-geek.org example.org
virtual_alias_maps      = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Here is `/etc/aliases`:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster: cmb
root: cmb
```

Note that `aliases.db` and `virtual.db` are both more recent than their plain-text counterparts, and `postfix` has been restarted to no effect. A test mail to `test@example.org` does this in `mail.log` (I've edited this log extract to make the domain `example.org`).

```
Aug 30 12:48:59 nova postfix/smtpd[32520]: 795B53D558: client=goggins.uwcs.co.uk[89.16.166.19]
Aug 30 12:48:59 nova postfix/cleanup[32530]: 795B53D558: message-id=<20090830114859.GA15341@warwickcompsoc.co.uk>
Aug 30 12:48:59 nova dkim-filter[2074]: 795B53D558 external host goggins.uwcs.co.uk attempted to send as uwcs.co.uk
Aug 30 12:48:59 nova dkim-filter[2074]: 795B53D558 ASP query: missing parameter(s) in policy data
Aug 30 12:48:59 nova spamd[2385]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] at port 38371 
Aug 30 12:49:00 nova spamd[2385]: spamd: using default config for test@example.org: /srv/chris.boyle.name/spamassassin/user_prefs 
Aug 30 12:49:00 nova spamd[2385]: spamd: processing message <20090830114859.GA15341@warwickcompsoc.co.uk> for test@example.org:1000 
Aug 30 12:49:05 nova spamd[2385]: spamd: clean message (-5.2/5.0) for test@example.org:1000 in 5.3 seconds, 1002 bytes. 
Aug 30 12:49:05 nova spamd[2385]: spamd: result: . -5 - AWL,BAYES_00,LOCALPART_IN_SUBJECT,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_MED,SPF_PASS,UNPARSEABLE_RELAY scantime=5.3,size=1002,user=test@example.org,uid=1000,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=38371,mid=<20090830114859.GA15341@warwickcompsoc.co.uk>,bayes=0.000000,autolearn=ham 
Aug 30 12:49:05 nova postfix/qmgr[32518]: 795B53D558: from=<cmb@warwickcompsoc.co.uk>, size=966, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 30 12:49:05 nova postfix/smtpd[32520]: disconnect from goggins.uwcs.co.uk[89.16.166.19]
Aug 30 12:49:05 nova postfix/local[32533]: 795B53D558: to=<cmb@chris.boyle.name>, orig_to=<test@example.org>, relay=local, delay=6.1, delays=6.1/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Aug 30 12:49:05 nova postfix/qmgr[32518]: 795B53D558: removed
```

Notice it being delivered to `cmb` at the end: I'd really love to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Robot101](http://robot101.net/) helped me solve this. The trick is that `virtual_alias_maps` will effectively recurse until the address is unchanged, and unqualified local parts on the right-hand side of the map will be qualified with `myorigin`, so this happens:

```
foo@example.org  -> newperson@chris.boyle.name -> cmb@chris.boyle.name
```

I can therefore work around it by changing `myorigin` to `nova.chris.boyle.name` (and fixing my address canonicalisation (using `canonical_maps`) to use `@chris.boyle.name` in sender addresses). This way, the mapping is onto `foo@nova.chris.boyle.name`, which the map will not alter any further, and which still has this machine as its final destination. Alternatively, I could have fully qualified the mappings with `@nova.chris.boyle.name`.