# Postfix and VirtualHosts

Tags: postfix

How can I setup postfix to automatically route mail to the correct UNIX user no matter which domain the mail comes in on.

For example, lets say I have 100 domains, and I want all mail that comes to webmaster@[every virtual host in /var/www/*] to end up in my single UNIX user webmasters ~/Maildir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is Postfix' `virtual_alias_maps`.

Some references:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/update-postfix-virtual-alias-map/

http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html

[Postfix: virtual_alias_maps delivering everything to one user despite new domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/60543/postfix-virtual-alias-maps-delivering-everything-to-one-user-despite-new-domain)