# Force PHP mail to avoid using postfix root@myorigin; use /etc/mailname instead?

Tags: php, email, postfix, sendmail, spf

I recently posted an issue setting up a mail server with postfix and virtual aliases. I solved the problem here:

[Postfix/Dovecot - Multiple Domains and Multiple Linux Accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/710618/postfix-dovecot-multiple-domains-and-multiple-linux-accounts/713446#713446)

To sum it up, I set `myorigin` to localhost, among some other settings. Sending and receiving mail via SMTP works great! However, when sending mail from `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, that is, PHP's `mail()` command, it's ignoring the `From:` header somehow, and instead grabbing the `myorigin` value.

Here's the headers of importance:

```
From: Me <user@example.org>
Return-path: <root@localhost>
Received: from example.org (example.org [104.xxx.xxx.xxx]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS...
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 104.xxx.xxx.xxx is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of root@localhost) client-ip=104.xxx.xxx.xxx;
```

When I change `myorigin` to `example.org` everything sends well with PHP, but completely decimates my ability to receive and send mail any other way. So that's not really a solution.

So what I'd like to do is tell `/usr/sbin/sendmail` to not use `myorigin`, but instead `/etc/mailname` **JUST FOR PHP**. I want to retain postfix's email everywhere else.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: This appears to be related to the `append_dot_mydomain` flag, which must be set to yes.

Comment: The following works from the command line, but **DOES NOT** work in the php.ini:  `/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t -f postmaster@example.org`

Comment: `mail.force_extra_parameters` doesn't seem to work either, ala: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#113849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so maybe I was a little hasty in posting this question. It turns out, this works great:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t -f postmaster@example.org
```

So, the real solution is then to use the

`mail.force_extra_parameters` flag, and set it to -fpostmaster@example.org

Just make sure you don't test using the cli php.ini, expecting the apache php.ini to work. Sheesh.